# GWT Async DataProvider always jumping to celtable' first page

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I have a simple celltable with:

a)A timer for retrieving the Whole list of values from the server (via rpc). when the data comes from the server:

```
public void onSuccess(final Object result) {

             myList ((List<myObject>) result);                            
             setRowData(myList);
        }
```

b)A AsyncDataProvider to refresh the current displayed page, where:

```
protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<myObject> display) {

            final Range range = display.getVisibleRange();
            int start = range.getStart();
            int end = start + range.getLength();

            List<myObject> dataInRange = myList.subList(start, end);
            // Push the data back into the list.                   
           setRowData(start, dataInRange);

}
```

This works fine, refreshing the table when new data arrives from the server ..BUT....It jumps to the first page of my displayed table regardless he current page (Page size=20).
It is like it is ignoring the start and dataInRange values of the onRangeChanged method

the sentence:
setRowData(myList);

Is firing properly the onRangeChanged event of the DataProvider, but some how the 'start' values get 0

Any tip?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call `setRowData(myList);` you also change the row range.

See the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#setRowData-java.util.List-):

> Set the complete list of values to display on one page.
>
> Equivalent to calling setRowCount(int) with the length of the list of values, setVisibleRange(Range) from 0 to the size of the list of values, and setRowData(int, List) with a start of 0 and the specified list of values.

Literally, below is the implementation:

```
public final void setRowData(List<? extends T> values) {
  setRowCount(values.size());
  setVisibleRange(0, values.size());
  setRowData(0, values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam.I see.....Actually what I'd really need is 'something' that triggers the 'onRangeChanged' of the DataProvider without change the current displayed page. In that way, the data will be refreshed with no user intervention........Is there any way for doing that?

Comment: See example code for [AsyncDataProvider](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/AsyncDataProvider.html). It's all there.